# Apply if row exist function on left join

Tags: mysql

I'm combining 3-6 tables using left join. Here's some example of the code on from clause

```
     FROM ip_ucp_01
LEFT JOIN ip_lt_01 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_lt_01.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_lt_01.date
LEFT JOIN ip_le 
       ON ip_lt_01.time = ip_le.time 
      AND ip_lt_01.date = ip_le.date
LEFT JOIN ip_lmiv_01 
       ON ip_le.time = ip_lmiv_01.time 
      AND ip_le.date = ip_lmiv_01.date
LEFT JOIN ip_cwg 
       ON ip_lmiv_01.time = ip_cwg.time 
      AND ip_lmiv_01.date = ip_cwg.date
LEFT JOIN ip_mtu_01 
       ON ip_cwg.time = ip_mtu_01.time 
      AND ip_cwg.date = ip_mtu_01.date
```

if there is no row on second table and third table, the data forth table and so on won't be displayed. I need to check whether the row on second table is exist or not. If so, it will use left join second table, if not it will use left join on third table and so on.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: just Change all your ON conditions to ip_ucp_01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you just JOIN with your first table? Like this:

```
     FROM ip_ucp_01
LEFT JOIN ip_lt_01 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_lt_01.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_lt_01.date
LEFT JOIN ip_le 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_le.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_le.date
LEFT JOIN ip_lmiv_01 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_lmiv_01.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_lmiv_01.date
LEFT JOIN ip_cwg 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_cwg.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_cwg.date
LEFT JOIN ip_mtu_01 
       ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_mtu_01.time 
      AND ip_ucp_01.date = ip_mtu_01.date
```

since you only join on date and time won't this do what you want?

Comment: Well, it isn't perfect answer. I changed how my system works to support this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think LEFT JOIN will work the way your are asking for ,because if there is no entry in parent table your won't be able to fetch data from grandchild .

In my opinion you can simple use CASE with Count (not best practice) but it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate `SELECT` queries for those `JOIN`s and `UNION` them all (with `DISTINCT`) into one query, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name
FROM (
 SELECT column_name
 FROM ip_ucp_01
  LEFT JOIN ip_lt_01 ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_lt_01.time AND ip_ucp_01.date =   ip_lt_01.date
  LEFT JOIN ip_le ON ip_lt_01.time = ip_le.time AND ip_lt_01.date = ip_le.date;

  UNION

  SELECT column_name
  FROM ip_ucp_01
  LEFT JOIN ip_lmiv_01 ON ip_ucp_01.time = ip_lmiv_01.time AND ip_ucp_01.date =   ip_lmiv_01.date

) a;
```